# Mesibo on-premises integration issue

Tags: mesibo, on-premises-instances

First, we completed the On-Premise Configuration on Mesibo console,
then after [step three](https://mesibo.com/documentation/on-premise/#step-4---configuring-tls-certificate) on their documentation
step 4 asks us to configure the TLS/SSL for Mesibo, but as we have already installed our SSL certificate on our server, we skipped it and ran the command in step 5, and it did run without any error but in the logs, we found what we have shown in the SS attached above.
Please help!

[enter image description here][2]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try troubleshooting here, it's quite detailed https://mesibo.com/documentation/on-premise/#troubleshooting--faq

If yes, what was the outcome?

By the way, you are exposing your database credentials in the image you have shared.